# Is Friction charging or Tribostatic charging, futuristic?

Tags: internal-consistency, power-sources

The charging of devices or other electronics by friction, futuristic ,or has it been already realized?

Also are solar and wind power charging more efficient? Should my civilization rely on those other than tribostatic charging?

Comment: Friction isn't a *power source*; the amount of power you get out is less than the amount of power you have to put in. I don't see any potential advantages or reasons to use friction as a general-purpose way of charging electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's real, today, but not as widespread as one would expect.

https://www.zmescience.com/science/triboelectric-energy-harvesting-403243/

"More efficient" depends on context. If I want fast charging of multiple devices,  tribostatics are not the charger of choice. For low volume charging over time, they look promising IMHO.